# How to make a python program append to a password protected file on Mac

Tags: python

I'm writing a secure password generator python program. I've written the code and I am able to write the desired information to the file as well, but I would like the file to be password protected(Owned by the Admin). And the program shows an error because it cannot access the file:

```
file = open("passwords.txt", "a")
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'passwords.txt'
```

How can I make it so that every time I run the program, it prompts the user to enter the file's password and then appends to it?

Here is my code so far:

```
import stdio
import stdrandom


def randChar(a):
    stdrandom.shuffle(a)
    return a[0]


def randLetter(a):
    stdrandom.shuffle(a)
    return a[0]


def u_randLetter(a):
    stdrandom.shuffle(a)
    y = a[0]
    return y.upper()

def rand_num():
    return stdrandom.uniformInt(0, 10)


def main():
    special_Char = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "-", "+"]
    alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k",
                "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

    password = []
    for i in range(4):
        password.append(randLetter(alphabet))
        password.append(rand_num())
        password.append(u_randLetter(alphabet))
        password.append(randChar(special_Char))

    stdrandom.shuffle(password)

    for j in range(len(password)):
        stdio.write(password[j])

    stdio.writeln()

    stdio.writeln("Username:")
    username = stdio.readString()
    stdio.writeln("Website:")
    website = stdio.readString()
    file = open("passwords.txt", "a")
    file.write(username + "\n")
    file.write(website + "\n")
    file.write("    Password: ")

    for j in range(len(password)):
        file.write(str(password[j]))
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: To my understanding you don't exactly have password protected files on Mac, you have files which are owned by another user (e.g. the admin superuser)... so what you may need to do is run your python script 'as' the user which owns the protected file. Try: `sudo python myscript.py` ... `sudo` should prompt you for the administrator password before running the script

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "password protected"? Are you relying on a feature from the operating system or are you implementing this protection yourself? 2. What error did you get from your current code? Please [edit] your question to include the full error message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The exact answer to your question will depend on how you choose to encrypt the file.  I don't see any information suggesting how you have chosen to do that.  Generally though, the standard approach would be to accept the password from the user, read any existing encrypted file's contents into memory, modify the in-memory copy, and then use the same password to rewrite the file to contain the new information.  Just how you read and write the encrypted file depends on what encrypt/decrypt operation you choose to use.

Comment: BTW, all of your random choosers can be replaced by `random.choice`.  No need to shuffle the whole list just to pick out one item.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are two options to solve this issue for you; if you want to add a password to your file on your mac, there is a [user guid](https://support.apple.com/en-il/guide/pages/tanca246d3ac).
There is also an option to do the same in a folder and hide it if you want.
If you want to be able to see the file still but the content will be unreadable. You can encrypt the file [example on how to do that](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/encrypt-and-decrypt-files-using-python/).
Note: you will have to save the key to decrypt the file content;
you can use the password in the following way.

1. chose a password (1 to 8 is excellent ;)
2. using this password to encrypt the data.
3. hash the password [example on how to hash](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/hash) and save it.
4. in the python script, check if the password after hashing it == to the saved hashed password.
5. if they are the same, use the password to decrypt the file content.